How to aggregate two rows returned by SQL query into one?
This is how I setup my test database:
-- Computer assets
CREATE TABLE tblAssets 
(
    AssetID int NOT NULL,
    AssetName nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    UserName nvarchar(150),
    PRIMARY KEY (AssetID)
);

-- Software titles
CREATE TABLE tblSoftwareUNI 
(
    SoftID int NOT NULL,
    softwareName nvarchar(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (SoftID)
);

-- Software installed on computer assets
CREATE TABLE tblSoftware 
(
    SoftwareID int NOT NULL,
    AssetID int NOT NULL,
    SoftID int NOT NULL,
    SoftwareVersion nvarchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (SoftwareID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblSoftware_tblAssets 
        FOREIGN KEY (AssetID)
        REFERENCES tblAssets(AssetID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblSoftware_tblSoftwareUNI 
        FOREIGN KEY (SoftID)
        REFERENCES tblSoftwareUNI(SoftID)
);

-- File existence on asset
CREATE TABLE tblFileVersions 
(
    VersionID int NOT NULL,
    AssetID int NOT NULL,
    FilePathfull nvarchar(1000),
    Found bit,
    PRIMARY KEY (VersionID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblFileVersions_tblAssets 
        FOREIGN KEY (AssetID)
        REFERENCES tblAssets(AssetID)  
);

INSERT INTO tblSoftwareUNI (SoftID, softwareName) VALUES (1, 'Adobe Acrobat');
INSERT INTO tblSoftwareUNI (SoftID, softwareName) VALUES (2, 'Microsoft Word');

INSERT INTO tblAssets (AssetID, AssetName, UserName) VALUES (1, 'PC1', 'Vito Corleone');
INSERT INTO tblAssets (AssetID, AssetName, UserName) VALUES (2, 'PC2', 'Jack Sparrow');
INSERT INTO tblAssets (AssetID, AssetName, UserName) VALUES (3, 'PC3', 'Han Solo');
INSERT INTO tblAssets (AssetID, AssetName, UserName) VALUES (4, 'PC4', 'Anakin Skywalker');
INSERT INTO tblAssets (AssetID, AssetName, UserName) VALUES (5, 'PC5', 'Harry Potter');

INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (1, 1, 1, '10.9');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (2, 2, 1, '11.0');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (3, 2, 2, '1.42');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (4, 2, 2, '2.57');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (5, 3, 1, '11.0');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (6, 3, 2, '2.57');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (7, 4, 1, '10.9');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (8, 4, 2, '1.40.9');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (9, 5, 1, '11.0');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (10, 5, 2, '1.40.9');
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareID, AssetID, SoftID, SoftwareVersion) VALUES (11, 5, 2, '2.57');

INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (1, 1, 'c:\temp\temp.txt', 0);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (2, 1, 'c:\test\testfile.txt', 0);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (3, 2, 'c:\temp\temp.txt', 1);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (4, 2, 'c:\test\testfile.txt', 1);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (5, 3, 'c:\temp\temp.txt', 0);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (6, 3, 'c:\test\testfile.txt', 1);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (7, 4, 'c:\temp\temp.txt', 1);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (8, 4, 'c:\test\testfile.txt', 0);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (9, 5, 'c:\temp\temp.txt', 1);
INSERT INTO tblFileVersions (VersionID, AssetID, FilePathfull, Found) VALUES (10, 5, 'c:\test\testfile.txt', 1);

I run this query:
SELECT
    tblAssets.AssetName,
    tblAssets.UserName,
    CASE LEFT(tblSoftware.SoftwareVersion, 1)
        WHEN '1' THEN tblSoftware.SoftwareVersion
        ELSE ''
    END AS v1,
    CASE LEFT(tblSoftware.SoftwareVersion, 1)
        WHEN '2' THEN tblSoftware.SoftwareVersion
        ELSE ''
    END AS v2,
    (SELECT TOP 1 tblFileVersions.Found 
     FROM tblFileVersions 
     WHERE tblFileVersions.FilePathFull = 'c:\test\testfile.txt' 
       AND tblFileVersions.AssetID = tblSoftware.AssetID) FileFound
FROM 
    tblSoftware
INNER JOIN 
    tblAssets ON tblSoftware.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
INNER JOIN 
    tblSoftwareUNI ON tblSoftwareUni.SoftID = tblSoftware.softID
WHERE
    tblSoftwareUni.softwareName LIKE 'Microsoft%'

Which returns:



AssetName
UserName
v1
v2
FileFound




PC2
Jack Sparrow
1.42

1


PC2
Jack Sparrow

2.57
1


PC3
Han Solo

2.57
1


PC4
Anakin Skywalker
1.40.9

0


PC5
Harry Potter
1.40.9

1



I would like to have only 1 line for each asset, so like this:



AssetName
UserName
v1
v2
FileFound




PC2
Jack Sparrow
1.42
2.57
1


PC3
Han Solo

2.57
1


PC4
Anakin Skywalker
1.40.9

0


PC5
Harry Potter
1.40.9

1



I cannot get my query results to my satisfaction. Can you help me?

Please give your question a meaningful title, that describes the problem

Have you looked at group by?

Please provide the sample data which produces your desired results.

GROUP BY the result.

Can you show us the sample data that you used to achieve your desired result

Looks like a pivot/conditional aggregation to me.

what if there are more than 2 versions ?

Good question @GuidoG. I choose to go for the most recent version. In this case the most recent version can be considered to be the active version within a major release.

@DaleK: I did not do that intentionally. Maybe it is because I'm a newbie but I wanted the foreign keys to be visible too.

Did not do what intentionally? The question guide, FAQ and [mre] example should be enough for even a newbie to ask a clear question. Or you can just keep in mind you are trying to explain your problem that you are intimately familiar with, to a complete strange, so you are going to have to provide enough information to get them up to speed.

This is achievable using left joins.
  Select  t1.AssetName,
      t1.UserName, t.SoftwareVersion, t4.SoftwareVersion,
        (select top 1 tblFileVersions.Found from tblFileVersions where tblFileVersions.FilePathFull = 'c:\test\testfile.txt' And tblFileVersions.AssetID = t1.AssetID) FileFound
    FROM tblAssets t1
    
    LEFT JOIN 
      (select t2.AssetId, t3.SoftID, t2.SoftwareVersion from tblSoftware t2 
      inner join  tblSoftwareUNI t3 on t3.SoftID  = t2.SoftID 
      where t3.softwareName Like 'Microsoft%' and Left(t2.SoftwareVersion, 1)='1') t
    on t.AssetId = t1.AssetId
    LEFT JOIN 
      (select t2.AssetId, t3.SoftID, t2.SoftwareVersion from tblSoftware t2 
      inner join  tblSoftwareUNI t3 on t3.SoftID  = t2.SoftID 
      where t3.softwareName Like 'Microsoft%' and Left(t2.SoftwareVersion, 1)='2') t4
    on t1.AssetId = t4.AssetId
    WHERE isnull(t.SoftwareVersion,'') != '' or isnull(t4.SoftwareVersion, '') != ''

see dbfiddle

Thanks @Ed Bangga. This solved my problem.

@JasperKimmel Then why don't you accept this answer officially, push the button :)
